# How to flip 2d skinned quadruped character?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, skinning

just would like to know is flipping 2d skinned character with one of scale axis good way for left or right movement(flipping direction and animation)?
Normal direction would change.(UPDATED)
for example i have a 2d skinned dog, and i wanna dog move left when i press left with same animation as right direction.
or is there any better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When drawing the character, you can scale it to -1 along the x axis to perform a flip. Additionally, the `sprite` object has a [`flip`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#flip%28boolean,%20boolean%29) function that will allow you to flip the sprite along the x or y axis.

It's a quick way to do left/right movement without redrawing everything. There are other ways to get this result (like creating new animations for the opposite direction), but if they're better or not is something only you can answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I also noticed on Rayman Legends, when character flipping, a simple transition animation helps for more realistic flip.